# (almost) Non-colliding simple hashing function for use in a switch

Tags: c, performance, hash, switch-statement

I am writing an advanced calculator in C. As you can guess, it currently has many functions, and I use a switch to do the proper operation for every function name. It goes something like this:

```
switch(hash_of(function_name_currently_being_parsed))
{
  case HASH_COS:
    // do something
    break;

  case HASH_SIN:
    // do something else
    break;

  // etc.
}
```

Up to now, I used this simple function I found somewhere on the internet to do the hashing:

```
#define NHASH 29989
#define MULT 31

unsigned int simple_hash(char *p)
{
  unsigned int h = 0;
  for(; *p; p++)
    h = MULT * h + tolower(*p);
  return h % NHASH;
}
```

It used to do the job just fine and is very fast. However, now that the calculator is expanding more and more, and also users can define their own functions and variables, collisions become quite noticeable -- for example `cond` and `dotp` both hash to 612.

Could somebody recommend a **fast** and **simple**, and as non-colliding as possible hashing function to replace the one I'm using right now? **Also, the table of the functions is NOT entirely hard-coded, the hashing function would also be used to hash the names of user-defined functions, for which a different way of checking a match is used, but the hashing function I use is the same.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you go about designing a function for a perfect hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734754/how-would-you-go-about-designing-a-function-for-a-perfect-hash)

Comment: The poster in that link is interested in a hashing function to hash a fixed table, but in my case, there can be new functions added by the user and so the table is not entirely static (for these, a different mechanism is used, switch is for the hard-coded ones). Edited post to clarify this.

Comment: There is no such thing like as a non-colliding hashing function. Maybe you mean mapping-function.

Comment: Short function names like sin & cos will be faster with strcmp than with hashtable lookup given that you have to generate a hash value at every occurance of a function name in the formula

Comment: What is the limit on the length of the user-defined functions names? (If there isn't one, then you can't have such a function unless the result of the hash function is also of unlimited length).

Comment: @caf: it's (arbitrarily) set to 64 characters, but in practice, it's usually shorter, let's say up to 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking for hash functions, have a look at both [Paul Hseih' Page](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html) and [Bob Jenkins' Page](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html)(this one is gold) on hashing, though personally I generally use [Murmur2](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) for hashing(with some different seeds), with the right seed, you won't get many(if any collisions) using a 32bit output, or even less(basically none, unless your purposely subverting the hash) using a 64bit version(I haven't tested 16bits though).

As for your problem, it might be easier if you used some form of binary search tree to lookup functions, seeing as there are user defined functions(a trie might even work)

Answer (score 0):

You could use trees for lookup. They have no collisions.